# Replace last values by first values in successive rows in a dataframe

Tags: r

I would like to replace the 2 "NA" at the end of one row by the first 2 values of the same row. And do this for each successive rows with "NA", i.e. 98 rows in my dataframe "Vracpop1".
I'm searching and searching, but I can't do it... Thanks for your help !

```
Vracpop1
    individuals pop loc1 loc2 loc3 loc4 loc5 loc6 loc7 loc8 loc9 loc10 loc15
1           1_1   1  499  501  500  500  500  500  499  500  500   499   501
2           499 501  500  501  500  500  499  500  500  500  500    NA    NA
3           1_2   1  499  501  500  500  500  500  500  500  500   499   501
4           499 501  500  500  500  500  499  500  500  500  500    NA    NA
5           1_3   1  499  501  500  501  500  500  499  500  500   500   501
6           499 501  500  500  500  500  499  500  500  500  500    NA    NA
...
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at the FAQ on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We need to see your code, as well as what you've tried in order to help you as best we can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of different ways to achieve this. Here is a base R solution:

```
df$individuals <- as.character(df$individual);
sel <- rowSums(is.na(df[, (ncol(df)-1):ncol(df)])) == 2;
df[sel, (ncol(df)-1):ncol(df)] <- df[sel, 1:2];
#  individuals pop loc1 loc2 loc3 loc4 loc5 loc6 loc7 loc8 loc9 loc10 loc15
#1         1_1   1  499  501  500  500  500  500  499  500  500   499   501
#2         499 501  500  501  500  500  499  500  500  500  500   499   501
#3         1_2   1  499  501  500  500  500  500  500  500  500   499   501
#4         499 501  500  500  500  500  499  500  500  500  500   499   501
#5         1_3   1  499  501  500  501  500  500  499  500  500   500   501
#6         499 501  500  500  500  500  499  500  500  500  500   499   501
```

Explanation: `(ncol(df)-1):ncol(df)` selects the last two columns; `rowSums(is.na(...)) == 2` returns `TRUE` if entries in the last two columns are both `NA`. In rows where `sel == TRUE` we replace `NA` entries in the last two columns with entries from the first two columns.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "    individuals pop loc1 loc2 loc3 loc4 loc5 loc6 loc7 loc8 loc9 loc10 loc15
1           1_1   1  499  501  500  500  500  500  499  500  500   499   501
2           499 501  500  501  500  500  499  500  500  500  500    NA    NA
3           1_2   1  499  501  500  500  500  500  500  500  500   499   501
4           499 501  500  500  500  500  499  500  500  500  500    NA    NA
5           1_3   1  499  501  500  501  500  500  499  500  500   500   501
6           499 501  500  500  500  500  499  500  500  500  500    NA    NA", header = T, row.names = 1)
```

Comment: But it is possible to improve the script because "individuals" that are written "*_" make some problem with the replacement.

Comment: I delete the "*_" by typing Vracpop1$individuals <- gsub("*_", "", Vracpop1$individuals) and it works.

Comment: @Fabrice I see; the problem was with `individuals` being a `factor`; so if you convert `individuals` to a `character` vector `df$individuals <- as.character(df$individual);` it should work as expected. I've made an edit to my post. Please take a look.

Comment: OK I took a look on your edit. Many thanks for all !

Comment: @Fabrice You're very welcome; if this answers your question, please consider closing the question by setting the check mark next to the answer.